# Why is Switch/Case syntax so different from the rest of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

Hopefully this isn't too philosophical, but it pertains to helping me understand Javascript and its conventions.

**Why does the Switch/Case syntax look so different from the rest of JavaScript?**

Specifically, I'm talking about the use of the colon, indentation, and the `break` keywords.

Does that exist in other places too?

It just sure looks a lot like python.

It also gets more confusing when you use TypeScript which makes use of colons for defining types.

Instead of this:

```
switch(foo){

  case 'bar':
    //do something
    break;

  case 'bizz':
    //do something
    break;

  default:
    //do something else
    break;
}
```

I would think it should be written like this:

```
switch(foo){
  case('bar'){
    //do something
  }

  case('bizz'){
    //do something
  }
  default{                 //or even an 'else'
    //do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: It's lifted almost straight from the [C syntax for switch statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm), the main difference being that in C you can only `switch` on a constant expression. It has nothing to do with Python, which doesn't even *have* a `switch` statement. Your proposed syntax looks good, but they aren't going to change it at this point (~25 years in).

Comment: It's along the lines of [`label`s and `continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: Also I would assume you meant `case('bar')`,

Comment: Your thought is definition of function, and I am not sure but whole language use same switch syntax, interpreter or compiler has to know exact what is it when reading code and your thought is function definition, they have to define function or switch block.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use curly braces in JavaScript/TypeScript switch case statements, which is similar to what you have written in your question.

```
switch(foo){
  case(bar): {
    //do something
  }

  case(bizz): {
    //do something
  }
  default: {               
    //do something else
  }
}
```

This actually created a block scoped statements within each case, which allows you to define the local `let` or `const` within each of them.

Answer (score 0):

because the Switch/Case syntax  is also:

```
switch(foo){

  case 'bar':
  case 'bizz':
    //do something for both
    break;

  default:
    //do something else
    break;
}
```